# Where is this still of Gambit and Wolverine stealing the Batmobile from?

Tags: dc, marvel, x-men, batman

I came across this page from a comic. Where is it from? Is it a crossover from Marvel to DC or vice versa?

[image: Page containing panels with images of the bat-mobile, Batman and Robin and Wolverine with Gambit.]

Comment: Where did find this still? Was it a loose leaf? Is there anything on the back? Any other clues?

Comment: Someone posted it on the Gambit facebook page.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is from a copy of the comic created in 1996 called Marvel vs DC. It is a scene from issue 2. You can read more about the comic series [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DC_vs._Marvel).

[image]

Comment: Yes...desperation at the time resulted in this